# Report Builder 3.0, how to sort on a calculated field

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2008, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0

I'm using Report Builder 3.0 with SharePoint Lists in SQL Server Business Intelligence Development Studio.

I have a textbox on the Tablix that calculates data from several fields using a VB.Net function in an expression.  This textbox displays a date that is generated from that function.

I would like for my report to be sorted by that date, ascending - I have been unable to find anything helpful on this thus far.  It is not a field in the dataset, so none of the canned options will work.

Thank you in advance for any assistance!

Comment: Well, the answer to this was:

use the same expression behind the field in the Sort properties of the Grouping properties, A-Z selected as the sort order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer was to use the same expression behind the field in the Sort properties of the Grouping properties, A-Z selected as the sort order.

Answer (score 0):

A calculated field will show up in a tablix as a normal one and should be entered as `Fields!cal.Value`